# Download image from URL synchronously

Tags: ios

I need to download an image file synchronously from the web, it's running in an async thread and the task in this thread needs to be synchronised.

I thought about using `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL`, but the documentation suggest to use it only for *short* files.

> can also be used for reading short files synchronously

What is a good alternative?

Comment: have you tried looking at libcurl?

Comment: By "short" files they mean files whose data can safely fit into memory. How big are the images (file size)? If the image files are just a couple of MB then you should be fine. If the images are much bigger than use the alternative shown in the docs for `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

Comment: @maddy Ah, ok. `dataWithContentsOfURL` is loading everything into memory. Since I'am not sure how big they are, I could use NSInputStream, right?

Comment: I updated my comment just as you replied. Please see it again.

Comment: Well, yeah. Seems like I have to use `NSInputStream`. How ironic that downloading an image **synchronously** is harder than asynchronously.

Comment: @Leandros for larger images the easiest solution might be to use AFNetworking or something similar.

Comment: @David I know about AFNetworking, but does it provide me a sync solution?

Comment: The issue has nothing at all to do with synchronous vs. asynchronous. It only has to do with data size. Either way, a large amount of data should be read in chunks and persisted to a file in chunks. Either way, a smaller file can be loaded completely into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a synchronous connection, you can use:

```
+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

a method of [**NSURLConnection**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a) which performs a synchronous load of the specified `URL` request. It returns the downloaded data for the `URL` request (image in your case).

Comment: I don't think the OP *want's a synchronous* method. Instead, he wants to solve a certain problem. And no matter what, there's no reason to use this *synchronous* method to accomplish this. Actually, the proposed approach is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommending you don't synchronously fetch big files. It's not recommending that this is a bad mechanism for synchronously fetching big files, but that you shouldn't be doing it in general. So just use that mechanism if you insist on ignoring the advice.

For the record: keeping an asynchronous thread alive but blocking on a synchronous process is less power efficient than using one of the runloop-injecting asynchronous mechanisms like `NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:...` or the delegate approach. Apple is thinking of battery life.

Answer (score -2):

As you are loading the data from the web, you should have read the following in the same documentation a few lines later, too:

> Important: Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs.

So, basically, no matter how large the data is, don't use this method for network requests!

The proper way is to use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`. For serious apps use the delegate approach.

For simple apps (toy and demo programs) you may use the *asynchronous* class convenient method of `NSURLConnection`: `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

There is no reason to use the synchronous convenient class method of `NSURLConnection`. Its usage is a code smell, since it wastes system resources for no purpose. So, simply don't use it! IMHO, it shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Ok, if you know that I don't want a synchronous method. What should I do, to keep my async thread synchronized? I'am iterating through an array of URLs, everyone links to an image. I need to download each image and when every download is finished, I need to call a block. What's the best way, in your opinion?

Comment: @Leandros Keeping things "synchronized" and executing a task synchronously is strictly not the same. You can be perfectly thread-safe with asynchronous methods as well. However, you did not say anything about *what* you want to accomplish, but rather you did say *how* you want to accomplish something (using a synchronous method). So, unless you mention *what* your issue is, it's difficult to suggest a solution. ;)

Comment: I'am iterating through an array with URLs (an unknown number of URLS), and these URLs are pointing to images, which I download. But I want to be notified when the process has finished, for dismissing the indicator that it's currently loading.

Comment: @Leandros Well, this is possible - either with _simultaneously_ loading the images, or _serially_. Either way, the whole operation then may also be asynchronous and can be wrapped into a method with a completion handler (e.g. `loadImagesWithCompletion:`).

Comment: The whole operation is asynchronous and has a completion handler. What's the best way, simultaneously or serially? My current approach uses a simultaneous approach by using `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` in an async thread.

Comment: @Leandros The best approach for downloading a number of *small* images is to load them _simultaneously_ - with a maximum number of concurrent requests of 4 to 6. Large images should be downloaded serially (or concurrently with a max number of 2). You may find solutions posted on SO for this specific problem on SO  ;)